# Getting error while using login with microsoft using firebase in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm using [firebase_auth][1] package to integrate login with Microsoft in my Flutter app.

I have followed all the official documentation.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth#ios+_1

But, I'm getting the below error.

`[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/invalid-credential] Error getting access token from microsoft.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: https://flutterdev-58b4c.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, response: OAuth2TokenResponse{params: error=invalid_request&error_description=AADSTS90023:%20Public%20clients%20can't%20send%20a%20client%20secret.%0D%0ATrace%20ID:%20f0f59fc3-915a-4772-9bbb-bcdc4242b200%0D%0ACorrelation%20ID:%205b0dd92e-1095-40ec-9a53-92e373a413c1%0D%0ATimestamp:%202023-07-14%2007:59:48Z&timestamp=2023-07-14%2007:59:48Z&trace_id=f0f59fc3-915a-4772-9bbb-bcdc4242b200&correlation_id=5b0dd92e-1095-40ec-9a53-92e373a413c1, httpMetadata: HttpMetadata{status=400, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, cacheDurationJava=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null, retryAfter=null, crossOriginEmbedderPolicy=null, crossOriginOpenerPolicy=null, crossOriginResourcePolicy=null, headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

And, This is the method.

````
    final microsoftProvider = MicrosoftAuthProvider();
    if (kIsWeb) {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(microsoftProvider);
    } else {
      final UserCredential result =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(microsoftProvider);
      print(result);
    }
  }```
````

Comment: you need to setup client secrets on firebase, did you do ?

Comment: Yes, I have already added the application ID and client secret value in my Firebase console Sign-in method.

Comment: Add the Client ID and Client Secret from that provider's developer console to the provider configuration:
To register a Microsoft OAuth client, follow the instructions in Quickstart: Register an app with the Azure Active Directory v2.0 endpoint. Note that this endpoint supports sign-in using Microsoft personal accounts as well as Azure Active Directory accounts. Learn more about Azure Active Directory v2.0.
When registering apps with these providers, be sure to register the *.firebaseapp.com domain for your project as the redirect domain for your app.

Comment: there is a section that tell you to add these credentials also on microsoft panel

Comment: You are right I have also added my redirection URL in Microsoft panel. Which I got from firebase.

https://flutterdev-58b4c.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler
Is it okay?

Comment: When registering apps with these providers, be sure to register the *.firebaseapp.com domain for your project as the redirect domain for your app. So i think you did right

Comment: Yes, I did that part.